# i have an array = [1 , 2 , 3 , ... , 100] and im trying to filter my array by numbers divide able by 3 . what i am doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is my array

```js
var hundred = [1 , 2 , 3 , ... , 100];

function divideByThree(array)
{
  return array.filter((a) => { 
    return (a / 3) === 0;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need modulo instead. Try like:

```
return (a % 3) === 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `%` instead of `/`

```js
var hundred = [1 , 2 , 3 , 9,100];

let divideByThree = (array) => array.filter(a => a % 3 === 0);

console.log(divideByThree(hundred));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the function and instead of `/` you need to use [Remainder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder) operator  which returns the remainder leftover. In your requirement the remainder left over need to be zero

```js
var hundred = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

function divideByThree(array) {
  return array.filter(a => (a % 3) === 0);
}
console.log(divideByThree(hundred))
```